# Can someone help me to know how I can make my layout work in small screen using css , css3?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout http://goo.gl/BgaiB that I want to make it work for the small screen device.

I want to know that how page can be set to auto re-size based upon screen size.

can someone help me how I can do this.

Regards,

Comment: I think hate is a bit extreme! - but before the OP moves into responsive design: Bootstrap, Foundation, Skeleton or whatever, they might consider updating their web skills. Frames are a bit old fashioned aren't they?

Comment: @NeilThompson, Don't let me wrong. someone else design the site. I just make it work for small device now. I have take a look on site's mockup already.

Comment: sure thing! http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ is a good start if you can change the css

Comment: @NeilThompson, just asked upfront why ridicule his skills, if we did not know context behind it : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media Queries is what you want, [here's a good overview:](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use some responsive web design techniques to have your layout change based on the device's screen width. Media queries is how you can accomplish this, and this [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) is a good starting point for learning about this technique.

Answer (score 1):

Using the media queries should do the job for you. Search for it.